# How to Bind Settings from Web.config using Ninject in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have a `Repository` that accepts a `Provider` which requires a `ProviderCredentials` object be passed into it. The `ProviderCredentials` object is a class, but it's values are only known at run time because they live in the Web.config in the `<applicationSettings />` section.

How can I take the values out of the Web.config, build the `ProviderCredentials` object and inject it into the `Provider` using Ninject? Not sure if it matters, but the `Provider` and `ProviderCredentials` classes live in a separate project than the MVC project in the same solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may consider binding `ProviderCredentials` by way of a factory method, forcing the kernel to resolve its reference using your own custom logic:

```
kernel.Bind<ProviderCredentials>()
      .ToMethod(context =>
             new ProviderCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"])
      );
```

Comment: That did it, except in my case I had to do `Settings.Default.???` to get the values out otherwise it was returning nulls. Thanks for the help, this is definitely easier than what I thought I was going to take.